# Grid search with cross-validation performing worse on test set than baseline model

Tags: logistic, classification, cross-validation, optimization, model-evaluation

I'm building a `LogisticRegression()` model in scikit-learn. Using `train_test_split()`, I've split the data into `X_train`/`X_test` and `y_train`/`y_test`.

First I create a baseline model:

```
baseline_mdl = LogisticRegression(solver = 'sag', C = 0.05, max_iter = 10000)
baseline_mdl.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))
f1_score(y_test, baseline_mdl.predict(X_test))
```

The F1 score is **~0.75**.

To find more effective hyperparameters, I run `GridSearchCV()`:

```
# The grid includes the hyperparameter combinations in the baseline model, plus other combinations.
grid = [{'solver': ['liblinear'],
         'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
         'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]},
        {'solver': ['sag'],
         'penalty': ['l2'],
         'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
         'max_iter': [10000]}]

search_mdl = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), param_grid = grid, scoring = 'f1', cv = 5)
search_mdl.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train));

search_mdl.best_params_
f1_score(y_test, search_mdl.predict(X_test))
```

The best parameters are: `{'C': 25, 'penalty': 'l1', 'solver': 'liblinear'}`

The F1 score is **~0.72**.

It's unclear to me why the "best" hyperparameters from the grid search model are resulting in worse performance on the test set compared to the baseline model. I realize that the grid search model is determining the best hyperparameters from `X_train` and not `X_test`, but I figured the performance on the test set would be just as good or better than the baseline.

Is it possible that the cross-validation in `X_train` is not able to learn the appropriate model parameters for predicting `X_test`, as compared to just training on `X_train` without the CV folds? Or is something else at play that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible with cross validation the is getting a better model. Try to see the performance of your baseline model along the cross validation folds. And it is somewhat overfitted for the test set. I would suggest making a more rigorous validation trying others test sets and even bootstrap the data in order to get better estimate of the F1-score.